# How do I allow connetction only to specific websites on windows7 (chrome and firefox)

Tags: windows-7, networking, google-chrome, firefox

The kids are getting on my nerv.
I have to leave open access to the laptop and the apps on it.
People in the family need to access a total of 3 sites on the internet while I'm gone.

How do i only enable the sites i want and block `*.*` everything else?

All of the block mechanics I know rely on the blacklist concept. I need to make a whitelist and ditch everything else...

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/) before to implement exactly what you are wanting.  You install and run this as a service, force your browser to use the proxy, and then use Privoxy's trustfile feature to setup a whitelist.

Comment: I'll check it out when i get back.

Answer (score 0):

The closest workaround I was able to put in action on the fly:
Setup useless DNS addresses on your net card or on your router, and put whatever site you want with its name and ip in the hosts file.

Skype dies too as I didn't really bother to see what servers it connects to.
Some other Internet dependent or DRM software might die too i suppose.